# Forward declaration in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an issue with forward declaration in `SKScene` I have to show a label node's value from game scene to game over scene , for example , but the value it returns as  `null` , here is my code :

GameOver Scene :

```
#import "MyScene.h"
@class MyScene;

@interface GameOver : SKScene {

MyScene *mainScene;

}


@implementation GameOver
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {     


           scores = [[SKLabelNode alloc]initWithFontNamed:@"Pixel LCD7"];
            scores.fontSize = 30;
            scores.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];

 //displaying score :
               scores.text = [NSString 
 stringWithFormat:@"Score:%@",mainScene.scoreLabel.text];


 scores.name = @"score";
            scores.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 230);
            [self addChild:scores];

}
```

MyScene

```
#import "MyScene.h"
@class GameOver;

@interface MyScene : SKScene {

 SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic) SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you initialise the label in wrong method.
Remove didMoveToView: method if you use it just to initialise and set up the label and move the code to initWithSize: method:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        // Your init code here
        scores = [[SKLabelNode alloc]initWithFontNamed:@"Pixel LCD7"];
        scores.fontSize = 30;
        scores.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];

        //displaying score :
        scores.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%@",mainScene.scoreLabel.text];

        scores.name = @"score";
        scores.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 230);
        self addChild:scores];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You should add property to your GameOver Scene to accept your score or override initWithSize: to for example initWithSize:score: and you should update your score label when you initialise game over scene.